# Web API 2 and EF attach issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web service I have developed using web api 2, which uses ef 6 to save the data back to the database.

My data structure is as follows;

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public int ContactId { get; set; }

    public string ContactName { get; set; }

    public int CreatedById { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CreatedById")]
    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public int ModifiedById { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ModifiedById")]
    public User ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}

public class Note
{
    [Key]
    public int NoteId { get; set; }

    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ContactId")]
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }

    public int CreatedById { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CreatedById")]
    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public int ModifiedById { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ModifiedById")]
    public User ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

I use the boiler plate code to try and save modifications for a note in the web api which is as follows

```
    // PUT: api/Notes/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutNote(int id, Note note)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != note.NoteId)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(note).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!AttachmentExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
```

When the line which modifies the entitystate is executed however, I get the following exception.

> Attaching an entity of type 'User' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

I find this puzzling as I'm not manually attaching any entites and the db.ChangeTracker.Entries() is empty at this point. I would have thought that the EF would handle the fact that the same entity could be referenced several times in a tree.

Has anyone come across this and does anyone have a solution for it ?

Many thanks in advance,

Neil.

Comment: you didn't even do anything with the `note` parameter.If you're making a `PUT` request, modify at least one property.

Comment: The modification would have been made client side and sent to the web api request, so the modification would already be contained in the note parameter.

Comment: I think Amit is pointing you in the right direction. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I believe part of the issue is that there's a possibility that your note *model* is never properly loaded into EF's object graph for tracking.

Try the following pseudo(ish) code:

```
// PUT: api/Notes/5
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
public IHttpActionResult PutNote(int id, Note note)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    if (id != note.NoteId)
        return BadRequest();

    //Not sure how you're setup, but have EF fetch the note you want
    //to modify from the DB. It is now aware of it and tracking changes.
    var model = _getNoteModelFromDbById(note.NoteId);

    //Now that you have the model from the DB you can map the properties 
    //of the incoming note to your model. Bellow is just a basic example.         
    //I recommend you look into a library called Automapper later on. 

     model.Title = note.Title;
     model.Description = note.Description;
     model.Status = note.Status;

    db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;

    try
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!AttachmentExists(id))
            return NotFound();
        else
            throw;
    }
    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I can see how what you are saying would work, however, if I apply your example verbatim, this means my controllers have to have a statement for every property on the object to update it, this isn't particularly friendly when it comes to maintenance and modification. If a class is updated at a later date it is likely that the controller maybe forgotten. You have addressed that in suggesting automapper but I have found then when using automapper to copy the properties then all the related objects are attached with a state of Added, which is obviously incorrect.

Comment: You are correct that the code is cluttered. It was just meant to be an example. You can refactor it by extracting the property mapping to it's own class. Then have a single line call to your converter/mapper in your controller. Ideally this should be done trough dependency injection. But if you are not familiar with the principle, no worries. It's outside of the scope if this question.

Comment: I'm on my phone at the moment, but I'd be happy to post some code examples later.

Comment: If you could that would be fantastic, many thanks for your help.

Comment: @PercivalMcGullicuddy could you please send the code examples?